# Is there a way to know if a website is in development mode or production mode in Django?

Tags: python, django, settings, production, development-mode

In Django, Because when in development and production mode, the settings.py file has to be so much different
For example

### **Development:**

```
DEBUG = true
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
...
EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
```

### **Production:**

```
DEBUG = false
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com']
...
EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN = 'https://example.com'
```

I don't know if there is **a condition to check if the app is in development mode or production mode** so that I don't hard-code it. The code should change automatically based on its mode.
I imagine something like this

```
if in_Development_Mode() == true:
   #code for devopmenet
else:
   #code for production
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:

```py
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG==True:
   #code for development
else:
   #code for production
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Comment: Thank you. In that way, I have to manually write "DEBUG = False" every time I upload the project to the server but I want that the condition automatically changes whether I write "DEBUG = False" or not

Comment: @Tai If you have different settings.py files for production and development, the code may not need altering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.getcwd()

If the current working directory is not the local directory then the website is in production

```
if 'C:\\Users\\UserName' in os.getcwd():
    DEBUG = True else:
    DEBUG = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to validate this using the `os.getcwd()` is to check for the production application folder.

```
if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    DEBUG = False # Set to false when in production
else:
    DEBUG = True # Set to true when not in production
```

Can use this for future reference as it can come in handy.